# Random points by percent coverage

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, random

Yes, I know the math behind this is simple, but I'm looking for a way to automate the process.

In ArcGIS 10.2.2. is it possible with the Create Random Points data management tool to generate a set of random points based on a percentage of the area of the constraining polygon? More specifically, I have a 1 meter square sampling plot I want to apply so as to cover 10% of the total area of any constraining polygon.

I can think of multiple ways to accomplish this, but they all involved manual intervention. I'm looking for a generic solution that is automated.